# Convert MMM DD, YYYY with timestamp to MM/DD/YYYY in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, datetime-format

I have a Google Sheet with dates in this format: `Jul 20, 2021, 1:57:53 PM`

Unfortunately, Google Sheets doesn't recognize this string to convert the date automatically to `MM/DD/YYYY`. What formula can I use to quickly convert 2000+ dates to `MM/DD/YYYY` format?

Here is a sample of some of the data I would like to convert and the type of result I'm looking for: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UcHNOtsMUNOvPcIYVXYRefFfNE6eLXavxFKk6Pp7sus/edit#gid=0

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.+),"), "mm/dd/yyyy")))
```

[image]

or if you need datevalue:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.+),"))))
```

Comment: The first one worked perfectly. Thank you so much!